# Kernel 3.13 on Ubuntu ARM + Android kernel options compatibility

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, configuration, android

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the kernel 3.13 on my ARM Samsung / Google Chromebook,using this tutorial :

http://www.virtualopensystems.com/en/solutions/guides/kvm-on-chromebook/

I have to say that ubuntu works really good. Now I would like to add the Android kernel options inside the `.config` file of the kernel.

Can you explain to me why when I add the options listed below to the kernel they disappear after the recompilation? If I look inside the .config file after the kernel is re-compiled, I don't see them anymore! These are the options that I need to enable:

```
CONFIG_ANDROID=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_IPC=y
CONFIG_ASHMEM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOGGER=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_PERSISTENT_RAM=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_RAM_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_TIMED_OUTPUT=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_LOW_MEMORY_KILLER=y
```

Maybe because this kernel is not compatible with Android? What should I do to make it what I want?

Comment: What exact sequence of commands are you using to download and unpack (or check out), compile, and configure the kernel?

Comment: you use a non standard kernel from the link. I would give a try to ask the creator of the tutorial why the kernel overrides your settings.

Comment: I edit the .config file by hand and I add manually the options listed above and then I do : $ ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make uImage dtbs

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution given to me by the author of the tutorial :

try running "ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf- make menuconfig" and enable the android staging options under drivers. In my experience this won't work that easily. Android has lots of stuff that are not mainline (at least in the past did), and most Android devices have their own kernel repositories for Android integration.

I would ask you to give me more detailed informations about how to do it : do you have a link that explains better how to do ? thanks.